# Variable in Web Api filter being ignored

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, filter

I would like to understand why the variable IgnoreRequest is always false after setting it to true in my web api 2.2.

The filter:

```
public class RestrictToCandidatePlus : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public virtual bool IgnoreRequest { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        bool validAccType = 2 == 1; //original code hidden
        if (!IgnoreRequest && !validAccType)
        {
            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }

    private void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse<String>(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Invalid account type");            
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
[Filter1]
[Filter2]
[RestrictToCandidatePlus]
public class PlusCandidateController : ApiController
{
    [RestrictToCandidatePlus(IgnoreRequest = true)]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage SetInterest([FromBody] SetInterestModel model)
    {
        //some logic

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

I have exactly the same logic with the filters on my MVC5 application and it works like charm. I understand that filters in MVC are not the same used in the Web Api, but I think that I should be able to set the IgnoreRequest variable to true.
As you can see, I cannot use OverrideActionFiltersAttribute, otherwise it will disable Filter1 and Filter2, which is not what I want.

Comment: I just tried your `RestrictToCandidatePlus` attribute on one of my controllers and when I hit a break point on the line `if (!IgnoreRequest && !validAccType)`  `IgnoreRequest` was true.

Comment: And this was on a WebApi 2.2? I know it works on MVC...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the issue. The problem was that the same filter was running twice, starting from the Action (HttpResponseMessage) then the Controller. So if I set the IgnoreRequest = true in the controller level I could see the value set to true.
But the main problem was that the filter was running twice, so to fix this I had to override the following property:

```
    public class RestrictToCandidatePlus : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public virtual bool IgnoreRequest { get; set; }

    public override bool AllowMultiple { get { return false; } } // <= HERE!

    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        bool validAccType = 2 == 1; //original code hidden
        if (!IgnoreRequest && !validAccType)
        {
            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }

    private void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse<String>(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Invalid account type");            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`IgnoreRequest` is always false because the controller level attribute  is being evaluated first and you are error handling out before can evaluate the action attribute..

Instead of using a bool to override or block your attribute evaluation you can  override the `ActionFilterAttribute` by using `OverrideActionFiltersAttribute`.

This will override any attribute inheriting from `ActionFilterAttribute` defined at the controller level.

Here is an updated attribute:

```
public class RestrictToCandidatePlus : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    // dont need this
    //public virtual bool IgnoreRequest { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        bool validAccType = 2 == 1; //original code hidden
        //if (!IgnoreRequest && !validAccType)
        if(!validAccType)
        {
            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }

    private void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse<String>(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Invalid account type");            
    }
}
```

Updated controller:

```
[RestrictToCandidatePlus]
public class PlusCandidateController : ApiController
{
    [OverrideActionFiltersAttribute]// <== new attribute here
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage SetInterest([FromBody] SetInterestModel model)
    {
        //some logic

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

You can create your own attribute class inheriting from `OverrideActionFiltersAttribute` if you want to give it your own name like `[OverrideCandidatePlus]`.

There is a great blog post [here](https://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/01/04/web-api-2-using-actionfilterattribute-overrideactionfiltersattribute-and-ioc-injection/) that explains how this works.

**Note:**
I have tested this with WebApi 2.2

Comment: Hi mate, many thanks for helping me out. Perhaps I should have mentioned this in the question, but in fact I am currently using this solution as a workaround. The reality is: I have 3 filters on top of the controller, but I need to ignore only one. If I use the OverrideActionFiltersAttribute, it will then ignore the other 2 filters. Hence why I need the IgnoreRequest boolean. Unless you have another suggestion to overcome this problem? Many thanks for trying to help again